# How to get variable value in JavaScript on event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function(){
   $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
       var myval = 123;
       console.log(myval);
   });
   $("#btn2").on("click",function(){
       console.log(myval);
   });
})();
```

How to get the value of myval on #btn2 event. (Getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: myval is not defined)

Comment: move the variable declaration from the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `myval` in a shared scope, so that the variable can be made accessible from the second method.

In your current code the variable `myval` is local to the first callback where it is declared, so it won't live outside the scope of that function.

```
(function(){
   var myval;
   $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
       myval = 123;
       console.log(myval);
   });
   $("#btn2").on("click",function(){
       console.log(myval);
   });
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4fe21hcx/)

Comment: still getting "undefined".

Comment: @Rahul you will get undefined if you click button 2 before button 1

Comment: @Rahul also don't forget to remove `var` from `var myval = 123;`

Comment: @Rahul try the attached fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4fe21hcx/1/ - try to recreate it there

Answer (score 1):

declare var myval out side click event function. to know more regarding variable scope in javascript you should read on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

```
(function(){
  var myval;

 $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
      myval = 123;
      console.log(myval);
  });

  $("#btn2").on("click",function(){
      console.log(myval);
  });

 })();
```